# Optional exception catching

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to make an exception that is optional to be caught?

In other words, an exception that can either:

- **be caught** in a try-catch block
- or **skipped** if no try-catch block exists for it

To visualize, I have a `ReportedException`, which is just a plain subclass of `RuntimeException`, and want to be able to catch it when it's needed:

```
try
{
    hideWindow();
}
catch (ReportedException ex)
{
    // Window could not be hidden.
    // Exception has already been caught and logged by parseInput(),
    // and now we're going to do something more.

    printAdditionalErrorMessage();
}
```

*Note: I edited the above example to better fit my question.*

or skip catching if the result is irrelevant:

```
hideWindow(); // We don't care if there was an error or not.
openAnotherWindow();
```

I know I can leave the catch block empty and have the same thing as above, but I use `ReportedException` very often and it would make my code highly unreadable.

If it's impossible (I suspect it is), what alternative/walkaround would you recommend?

*P.S. The method names used in the examples are just foo's and bar's.*

**EDIT:** I know I don't need to catch RuntimeExceptions. What I want is to ignore them if they occur.

Comment: What do you mean with "ignore"? They should not be printed to concole`?

Comment: Do not use exceptions for normal flow of control. Except for system failures, there should generally be a way to write code that avoids exceptions being thrown. For example, you can provide a way to check preconditions before calling a member to allow users to write code that does not throw exceptions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx

Comment: @TimHerold They are printed to console by hideWindow(), not by the code you see in the example.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want.  A Java exception, if not caught, will ALWAYS be "bubbled up" to the next outer scope.  (This is unlike exception-like events in, IIRC, PL/I, COBOL and some other languages.)  At best you can add exception handlers that will catch and ignore the exceptions (hopefully after at least logging them).

Comment: @HotLicks You mean empty catch blocks? If not, please describe what do you mean by an exception handler.

Comment: (Also, the IBM iSeries Control Language (CL) had something like this, where any invocation could sort of stick out a hook for exceptions, and certain exceptions, if not specifically "hooked" would be ignored.  This was accomplished, IIRC, using an event mechanism, rather than exceptions.)

Comment: I mean, the only way to do this, in Java using the exception mechanism, it to place try/catch blocks where you want the exceptions ignored and code the catch block to swallow the exception.

Comment: So, as you say, there is no way to do it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Better would be to have a way for your handler "advertise" that it wanted to handle the exception somehow, and only signal the exception if someone said they wanted to catch it.  This would probably require a task-local counter of "advertisements" that would be incremented/decremented by the catching routine (inside a try/finally range to assure decrement occurs on exit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little fuzzy on how to use ThreadLocal (and there are apt to be some other tupos), but something like this:

```
public class IgnorableException {  

     static class DontIgnoreCount  {
         int count;
     }

     // Thread local variable containing each thread's ID
     private static final ThreadLocal<DontIgnoreCount> dontIgnoreCount =
         new ThreadLocal<DontIgnoreCount>();

     static void incrementDontIgnore() {
         DontIgnoreCount counter = dontIgnoreCount.get();
         if (counter == null) {
             counter = new DontIgnoreCount();
             dontIgnoreCount.set(counter);
         }
         counter.count++;
     }

     static void decrementDontIgnore() {
         DontIgnoreCount counter = dontIgnoreCount.get();
         // Must not be null here
         counter.count--;

     static bool shouldSignal() {
         DontIgnoreCount counter = dontIgnoreCount.get();
         return counter.count > 0;
     }
}
```

To use, invoke DontIgnoreCount.incrementIgnoreCount() early in try range, and DontIgnoreCount.decrementIgnoreCount() late in finally range.

When signalling an exception that follows this protocol, only signal it if shouldSignal returns true.

```
void iWannaCatchException() {
    try {
        IgnornableException.incrementDontIgnore();
        int x = someOptionallySignallingMethod();
    }
    catch (...) {
        ...
    }
    finally {
        IgnorableException.decrementDontIgnore();
    }
}

void iDontWannaCatchException() {
    int x = someOptionallySignallingMethod();
}

int someOptionallySignallingMethod() {
    if (somethingBad) {
        if (IgnorableException.shouldSignal()) {
            throw new BadException();
        }
    }
    return 42;
}
```

Note that not shown above are any `throws` clauses you'd have to add to keep the compiler happy.  This mechanism would not remove the need for those.

You could also inplement a delegate/observer scheme, replacing the simple counter with a stack of observer objects, and pass a message to the observer vs throwing the exception.  But this, by itself (without coupled exceptions/try ranges) would not allow blowing away the stack to the appropriate recovery point.

Comment: By what you suggested in the comments, I thought you meant less-or-more something like observer pattern where, in case of exception, observers are updated. Can you show a real example of how to use it, please? I would appreciate.

Comment: I added ``static { dontIgnoreCount.set(new DontIgnoreCount()) }`` after ``dontIgnoreCount`` declaration (otherwise shouldSignal() throwed ``NullPointerException``) and now it works perfectly! Thank you, Hot Licks!

Comment: But can you tell me one more thing? Why are you using here ``ThreadLocal`` instead of ordinary variable?

Comment: You need the don't ignore count to be on a per-thread basis, since it must track the call-return history of the thread.  If it were global, and you had two threads running, you might signal an exception in the wrong thread -- one that wasn't saying it wanted it.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you once again. This is **exactly** what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions should be used for exceptional situations.

From your example, if the window not being hidden is a typical event, it shouldn't throw an exception. If that is your function, then use a return value to indicate whether it was successful instead of throwing an exception. Then you can safely ignore the return value when you don't care if it succeeded or not.

If you do not have control over that method, then you can wrap it in another method that catches the exception and turns it into a return value. E.g.

```
private boolean tryHideWindow() {
    try {
        hideWindow();
    }
    catch (ReportedException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you need some parameters of the exception to determine what to do, then you could return the exception instead.

```
private static class MyReturnType {
    private final Throwable thrown;
    private final OrigRtnType returnVal;
    public MyReturnType(Throwable thrown) {
        this.thrown = thrown;
        this.returnVal = null;
    }
    public MyReturnType(OrigRtnType returnVal) {
        this.thrown = null;
        this.returnVal = returnVal
    }
    public boolean wasExceptionThrown() {
        return thrown != null;
    }
}

private MyReturnType tryHideWindow() {
    try {
        OrigRtnType returnVal = hideWindow();
    }
    catch (ReportedException ex) {
        return new MyReturnType(ex);
    }
    return new MyReturnType(returnVal);
}
```

This is an answer to your question, but it is not necessarily a good idea. As others will doubless comment, using exceptions for program flow is less than ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, the methods that throw ReportedException already return a value.

Comment: And no, I don't use it for flow control, but - as this is for a game plugin - mainly for telling player he did something wrong and just it.

Comment: @LucasEasedUp then you can either return type Object and check the return type via instanceof (highly not recommended) or return both values (original return value + optional exception) by wrapping them in a wrapper class.

Comment: That may be the solution.

Comment: @LucasEasedUp Edited to indicate what I was referring to. Again, not recommended.

Comment: Ok, if no-one come up with a better solution, it'll be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use exceptions for flow control, rather than for reporting truly exceptional cases.

Using exceptions for flow control is typically frowned upon. The common approach is to return a success/failure indication as the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
try{
    hideWindow();
}catch (ReportedException ex){
    // ingore

}catch (NullPointerException ex){
       killWindow();
}finally  {
    //to do something more.
}
```